# Pass information from view to view

Tags: angularjs

I have a multistep form where information from the first steps should be available to the next ones.

How do I share this information between views? Should I append the models in the `$rootScope` or create a common parent controller?

Comment: Here's a [very primitive demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3UW36wlpBjgCsSy7s0G2?p=preview) of 3 forms, each with own controller, sharing data from a service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service to store the shared items, since services are singletons.  Here's an arbitrary example.

```
sharedDataExampleModule.service('SharedData', function(){
    var data = {};
    // API to get/set shared data
    return {
        getData: function(){},
        setData: function(data){}
    };
});
```

Inject the service into any controller that needs to access the data.

```
sharedDataExampleModule.controller('ControllerA', function($scope, SharedData){
    // set data
    SharedData.setData($scope.objectContainingOurSharedData);
});

sharedDataExampleModule.controller('ControllerB', function($scope, SharedData){

    // get data
    $scope.shared = SharedData.getData();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First View Controller, passing the object param:

```
function FirstViewController($scope) {
    $http.post(url).success(function(objModel){
        $scope.objModel = objModel;
    }).error(function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    });
}
```

Second View Controller, get the params:

```
function SecondViewController($scope, $params) {
    var objModel = $params.objModel;
}
```

I hope to help you.